# Extract div without sup or span

Tags: html, xpath

I need to extract prices for a website using Xpath 1.0, running it through Screaming Frog

The HTML on the page is as follows:

```
<div class="artikel-price">
6,99 €<sup>1</sup><span class="artikel-price-amount">6,99 € / kg</span> </div>
```

I need to return just the "6,99 €" contained within the first `<div>`. `//div[@class="artikel-price"]` returns "6,99 €1(6,99 € / kg)" for all pages.

```
     //div[@class="artikel-price"]/text()
```

returns the correct result, but only for 3 of the 10 URLs, the others don´t return a result at all (many thx to @Diego-D for this code!)

The difference seems to be that the HTML for the other pages is

```
<div class="artikel-price">
<b>3,49 €<sup>1</sup></b><div class="artikel-price-amount">6,98 € / kg</div> </div>
```

so with the added `<b>`and with `</div> </div>` at the end instead of `</span> </div>` . Could it be that that breaks the code, and if so, how do I rectify that?

Comment: did you try `//div[@class="artikel-price"]/text()`?

Comment: Hello @DiegoD, thx a lot for the reply, one step closer it seems :) I´ve updated the question, could you have another look? I don´t know how to add that info into a comment so I needed to add it into the question and rephrase the question itself.

Comment: Do you know anything about what you are doing? The prices with b in them just need selector edited so that it matches div with b inside and then .text() So you extract using one or the other depending if there is a b inside that div or not. so its either what you have or with /b/text() in the end

Comment: I understand if you were missing the trick on how to tell to the selector to grab the text node content only but now that you know it, it shouldn't be hard to make a try and make your selector more specific. You have all the information on how to go down with the parent-child chain (`/`), how to specificy the element type and how to specify an attribute value. The question shows that you didn't even try

Comment: I am sorry, but the intro I wrote, where I explained that i do not have a technical background and know next to nothing about coding seems to have been deleted (and the "Hello all" as well).

So its not that I haven´t tried (on the contrary, I´ve been at this for hours), its just that I do not know what I´m doing, as @codesmith so eloquently put it.
I understand that it is probably an easy question if you know what you´re doing, unfortunately I do not :(

Comment: But many thx to the both of you, I (well, actually you guys obviously) solved it. 


```
     //div[@class="artikel-price"]/text()
``` 

for the one situation and


```
     //div[@class="artikel-price"]/b/text()
``` 

for the other. I almost missed that. I am really sorry you had the impression I hadn´t tried myself, I can only assure you I did.